# Sentences true or false?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following sentences:

1: ∅ ∈ {0}

2: {1} ∈ {1, {2, 3}}

3:   2 ∈ {1, {2, 3}}

4:  1 ∈ {R}

I know that the number 1 is true and all the others are false, but I can't understand why.

Thank you very much!

Comment: None of them are true for me

Comment: my book says the first one is true and I can't even understand why are the others false? :P

Comment: I'd be tempted to say that they'r all false.

Comment: And why? :/ Thank you anyway!!

Comment: If your book says the first item is true, then you have two options: (1) your book considers that zero is equal to the empty set; (2) you must use other book.

Comment: You should be careful to distinguish "$\subseteq$" and "$\in$". Are you sure you mean "$\in$" in each of these statements? Also, is your first set supposed to be $\{0\}$ or $\{\varnothing\}$?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @BenjaminMoss the empty set is *contained* in every set vacuously, but it is not an element of every set.

Comment: @MPW Yes, everything is like it is in my book! :P

Answer (score 1):

If your book says (1) is true, then your book has a typo. Both of the alternative statements
$$\varnothing\subseteq\{0\}$$
and
$$\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}$$
are true, but not the statement in (1).

(2) is false because the only elements of the set on the right are $1$ and $\{2,3\}$, but not $\{1\}$. Note that "$1$" and "$\{1\}$" are not the same thing. It's analogous the difference between an egg and an egg carton containing an egg. The alternative statements
$$\{1\}\subseteq\{1,\{2,3\}\}$$ and $$1\in\{1,\{2,3\}\}$$ are true.

(3) is false for similar reasons. $2$ is not in the set on the right; rather, it is in an element of a set that is in the set on the right. Again, think of the analogy mentioned above. A possible true alternative compound statement might be $$2\in\{2,3\}\in\{1,\{2,3\}\}$$

(4) is false because the only element of the set on the right is $\mathbb R$, and $1\neq\mathbb R$. As in (3), a true alternative might be $$1\in\mathbb R\in \{\mathbb R\}$$

Comment: Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: You're welcome. The important thing is -- do you understand why my answers are correct?

Comment: @ MPW I've understand everything you said!! :) But there is still something that I'm not understanding. I don't know if this is the correct place to ask you this, but, hoping it is, here it goes:   What's the difference between:  {1} ∈ {1, {2, 3}}  and  {1} ⊂ {1, {2, 3}}?  Thank you!

Comment: @MiguelFerreira This answer is not correct if your book defines $0$ as the set $\emptyset$, which is a valid definition.

Comment: @Hellen : That is **extrememly** unlikely, especially since the book is using the symbol $\varnothing$ explicitly, since it is intermixing other numerals in the same context, and since it is using **both** symbols in the same question (1). If you think along those lines, it is possible (but even more unlikely) that the book defines "$2$" to mean the set $\varnothing$, right?

Comment: @MiguelFerreira : If you think of a set as a list of items, then the difference is that $$1\in\{1,\{2,3\}\}$$ states that "$1$ is an item in the list". But $$\{1\}\subseteq\{1,\{2,3\}\}$$ states that "every item in this list is also an item in the other list".

Comment: No, it is not right.

Comment: @MPW Thank you so much! I'm now understanding all this :))

Comment: @Hellen : Can you be specific? What is not right?